# Are Rational Power of e is transcendental?

Tags: analysis, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, transcendental-numbers, irrationality-measure

It is well known to all of us that the rational powers of $e$ are irrational numbers. Many of the proofs proving this use a similar approach as proving $e$ irrational using Niven's Polynomials. Is it true that rational powers of $e$ are also transcendental numbers using proofs similar(as proved by Hermite) for proving $e$ transcendental?

How to measure the irrationality measure of those rational powers of $e$?

Comment: Not sure if this is counts, but the Lindermann-Weierstrass theorem establishes the transcendence of $e^a$ for any algebraic (and hence rational) number $a$. I don't know how to answer your question about the irrationality measure of these numbers.

Comment: Perhaps you are aware that rational powers of algebraic numbers are algebraic. Hence all rational powers of $e$ are transcendental (except $e^0=1$).

Answer (score 1):

In field theory language: We have $\mathbb{Q}(e^{m/n})\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(e^{1/n})$ so WLOG we may consider $e^{1/n}$. Observe $\mathbb{Q}(e^{1/n})/\mathbb{Q}(e)$ is finite and $\mathbb{Q}(e)/\mathbb{Q}$ is infinite, so $\mathbb{Q}(e^{1/n})/\mathbb{Q}$ is infinite: $e^{1/n}$ is transcendental.